# Union of two measurable sets is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I was reading the proof of the following Lemma:

If $E_1, E_2$ are two Lebesgue measurable sets then their union and intersection are also Lebesgue measurable.

The proof is as follows:

Denote by $m^*(E)$ the outer measure of a set $E$.

We are only going to prove the case of union of two sets, the case of intersection is proven similarly.

We know that a set $E$ is called measurable iff for every $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ it holds $$m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)$$ where $E^c$ is the complement of $E$. In our case this relation holds for the sets $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Furthermore for every $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ $$A = (A\cap E) \cup (A\cap E^c)$$ and using the subadditivity of outer measure we have: $$m^*(A)\leq m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)$$

So to prove that a set is measurable we only need to prove the reverse inequality (because if they are both true then equality must hold): $$m^*(A)\geq m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)$$

Thus, in our case we want to show: $$m^*(A)\geq m^*(A\cap (E_1\cup E_2))+m^*(A\cap (E_1\cup E_2)^c)$$

We know that $E_1$ is measurable so $$m^*(A)= m^*(A\cap E_1)+m^*(A\cap E_1^c)$$

Now, this is where my trouble begins. The book states: As $E_2$ is also measurable it holds $$m^*(A\cap E_1^c)= m^*(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2)+m^*(A\cap E_1^c\cap E_2^c)$$

I do not seem to understand where this last relation is coming from. The definition states that the first relation must hold for **every** subset of $\mathbb{R}$ on the left hand side, but the set $A\cap E_1^c$ is always a subset of $E_1^c$ and cannot thus run through all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. What am I missing? The proof finishes by manipulating the last two relations and the subadditivity of outer measure.

I have searched on SE, but couldn't find any similar questions or methods of proof. It would mean the world if somebody could give me a little insight. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already stated that $E_2$ is measurable iff for every $B\subset\mathbb{R}$

$m^*(B)=m^*(B\cap E_2)+m^*(B\cap E_2^c)$.

Set $B:=A\cap E_1^C$.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your effort! If I am not mistaken you are doing the following: $B$ can be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$, however here we use a weaker property: if $B$ can be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it can also be a subset of $E_1^c$, so in this step only consider those sets that are subsets of $E_1^c$ (as $A$ can be any set and the intersection of two sets is a subset of both). Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly.